# How to split and concatenate a string

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a filename in a string. I want to split the given string into 2 (1 is filename without extension, 2 is only extension) strings. Then add `_dev` to the end of first string and concatenate with 2nd one.

ex:

```
Dim name as string="abc.txt"
Dim finalName as string
```

The `finalName` should be like this `"abc_dev.txt"`

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dim newName as String = oldName.Insert(oldName.LastIndexOf("."), "_dev")
```

---

Refer to:

[String.Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx)

[String.IndexOf Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)

[String.LastIndexOf Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy.aspx)

---

Comment: In case there is a good reason for the down vote here, am I supposed to implicitly figure it out ??

Answer (score 2):

If they're really filenames:

```
 ' unested, likely to contain spelling errors
 name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldName)
 ext = Path.GetExtension(oldName)
 newName = odlName & "_dev"
 newName = Path.ChangeExtension(newName, ext)
```

Comment: +1, Absolutely using `System.IO.Path` static class is the most clearest solution. I think no need to deal with `String.Split` and `String.Insert`

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
finalName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name) & "_dev" & Path.GetExtension(name)
```